# Unable to Open Settings of application with Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions, android-settings

I'm dealing with android app permissions in which if the user denied permission permanently I need to move the user to app Settings to enable the permission manually.
All the code working fine but when I start an Intent to move the user to Settings of my app I'm getting activity not found Exception.

Here is the Exception

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS dat=Package:com.e.permisions }
```

This is my code

```
package com.e.permisions;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button request;
    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilising buttons
        request = findViewById(R.id.request);


        request.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //Todo: Code to do what if permissions granted...
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permissions Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                        //Todo: usually we should show alert why should need these permissions...
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                .setTitle("Why these Permissions?")
                                .setMessage("For App functionality we need these permissions..")
                                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                                    }
                                })
                                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                        //Todo: request permissions when click ok
                                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, permissions, 123);
                                    }
                                })
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .create().show();
                    } else {
                        //Todo: request permissions
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, permissions, 123);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 123) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Todo: code to do what if permissions are Granted...
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions are Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                //Todo: if permissions Denied permanently by user..
                gotoSettings();
            } else {
                //Todo: what to do if denied
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void gotoSettings() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Go to Settings")
                .setMessage("enable the permission")
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Moving to Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        try {
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("Package", getPackageName(), null);
                            intent.setData(uri);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "failed to open Settings\n" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.d("error", e.toString());
                        }

                    }
                }).create().show();
    }
}
```

Also updates permission details in the manifest file.
Anyone can help what's going wrong with this code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are giving "Package" in

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("Package", getPackageName(), null);
```

Because of the case sensitivity it is not finding the view, Try giving `package` as given

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
```

Comment: I wasted so much time for this. It's working now. Thanks for fast response.

Comment: Welcome, Please accept the answer if you found it helpful @RealTechHacks

Answer (score 3):

```
try this way ...
private void gotoSettings() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Go to Settings")
            .setMessage("enable the permission")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Moving to Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    try {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(
                                    Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package",
                                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null);
                            intent.setData(uri);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "failed to open Settings\n" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("error", e.toString());
                    }

                }
            }).create().show();
}
```

Comment: It's working now thanks for fast response.

Comment: instead of writing everything in detail if you point out what's wrong in the code and what should OP do then it will also help others who might face the same issue in the future.

Comment: Sure, I'm new to stack overflow. I will improve my questions asking skills next time .